# How to execute gp.execute ArcSDE tool in C#

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, c#, arctoolbox

So I created an ArcGIS 10 toolbox in ArcSDE and added a tool to it. 
There are enough examples out there on how to execute a tool.tbx that resides outside SDE or GeoDB. 
But in C#, how do you use gp.execute on a tool that resides **within ArcSDE**?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [IToolboxWorkspace](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IToolboxWorkspace_Interface/002n0000051q000000/) interface.  Code below works for a file gdb workspace, I'd imagine it would work for arcsde too.

```
private static void ListToolboxes(IWorkspace ws)
{
    var tbxWkspc = ws as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.IToolboxWorkspace;
    if (tbxWkspc == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not a toolbox workspace");
        return;
    }
    var toolboxes  = tbxWkspc.Toolboxes;
    toolboxes.Reset();
    IGPToolbox tbx;
    while ((tbx = toolboxes.Next()) != null)
    {
        var tools = tbx.Tools;
        tools.Reset();
        IGPTool tool;
        while ((tool = tools.Next()) != null)
        {
            // you could execute here ...
            //tool.Execute
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", tbx.PathName, tool.Name);
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I was able to find my toolbox & tool in ArcSDE. Kirk, another question. Instead of enumating thru the tools and finding a hard-coded tool name to execute, could you have the name of the tool in something like a config.xml which you could read? I will probably need to fire different tools so I am looking for flexibility. Or how would you handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you'd need the name of the toolbox and the name of the tool.  Open the toolbox with [IToolboxWorkspace.OpenToolBox](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenToolbox_Method/002n0000051w000000/) and then open the tool with [IToolBox.OpenTool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenTool_Method/002n000003vm000000/).

Comment: I ended up using Geoprocessor gp because it was easier. I could not figure out the parameters of IGPTool.execute, because the developer help is vague with no examples. Also, I am running my custom ArcSDE model tool from a console app... Sorry, I must not have been clear. I was wondering if I could save the name of my tool and its parameters to an external xml file so I would never have to update my c# code when a new custom tool is created. thanks!